# How to add a condition (rule) to skip questions when using the Quiz module?

Tags: quiz

I'm using [Quiz](https://www.drupal.org/project/quiz) module and I have a quiz with questions 1 to 10.

I want this:

Question 1: If answer is yes **jump** to question 2. If answer is no jump to question 7.

How can I achieve this? Do I need to use [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module?

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work using the [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) module (which I'd also use for this), you should ALSO use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module. Some more details about this module (from its project page):

> ... provides [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) plugins for conditionally altering execution flow directly inside a group of **actions**.

Some examples of using the Conditional Rules module:

- "[How to check whether one's current User Points are negative with the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/88888/how-to-check-whether-ones-current-user-points-are-negative-with-the-rules-modul/205971#205971)" contains an example of a rule (in Rules export format) with an action that uses Conditional Rules with a typical "if"-part and "else"-part.
- a screenprint of a rule with an action that uses Conditional Rules, though only with an "if"-part here, no "else":

  [image]

So by using both of these modules, you could use a **Rules Action** to redirect (= jump) to either question 2 or question 7, based on the answer (yes or no) provided to question 1.

This would answer your question for "question 1". By creating up to 10 similar rules (1 for each question that has a similar requirement), you should have a solution for all other questions that would need it also. However, you should be able to take advantage of other facilities that the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module offers (by constructing complex conditions as a condition set and then use those in the condition elements). So that you include all the required logic (for all your 10 questions) in a single Rule.